# Is the following series infinitely differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

Let $f:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R},\, f\in C^\infty,\, f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and consdier the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
I want to show that this series defines an infinitely differentiable function $F$ on $\mathbb R.$
 I suppose all I need to show is that $\sum f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly, but I don't know how to show that. I know that if $\sum f'\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly and $\sum f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges pointwise for some $x$, (e.g. 0),  then $\sum f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$  converges absolutely, but that didn't make it any easier. 
Is my approach correct? If so, how do I proceed?

Comment: "I suppose all I need to show is that $\sum f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ converges uniformly" I'm not sure why you say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start: For any $x$ Taylor gives

$$\tag 1 f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + f''(c)x^2/2= f''(c)x^2/2$$

for some $c$ between $0$ and $x.$ Let $R > 0,$ and let $M_R = \sup_{[-R,R]} |f''|.$ If $|x|\le R,$ then from $(1)$ we see

$$|f(x/n)| \le M_R|x/n|^2/2 \le M_R R^2/n^2.$$

By Weierstrass M, $\sum f(x/n)$ converges uniformly on $[-R,R].$ It follows that $F$ is continuous on $[-R,R].$ Since $R$ is arbitrary, $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb R.$

These ideas should be helpful in showing that $F^{(n)}(x)$ eixsts for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and $n\in \mathbb N.$

Comment: Can you plz explain more that why $F \in C^{\infty} $ ?

Comment: @Ashkan To show $F$ is differentiable, it's enough to show $\sum f_n'$ converges uniformly on any $[-R,R].$ Note $f_n'(x) = f'(x/n)\cdot (1/n).$

Comment: AFAIK, uniform convergence doesn't persevere differentiability

Comment: @Ashkan Right, but I'm talking about uniform convergence of the series of derivatives.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if $\sum f_n'$ converge s uniformly ,how do we know it  converges to $F'$

Comment: @Ashkan See Theorem 1 of http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131bh.1.03s/week45.pdf